# Call server side function from javascript asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to track when a user clicks play on a wistia embedded video. Basically I just need to write to a SQL DB the name of the video and the logged in user. I have everything built but I need to call the server side function from the javascript. Here is the script code:

```
<script>
    wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("zt4tf4py2t");
    wistiaEmbed.bind("play", function () {
    alert("Play"); // CALL C# FUNCTION HERE
    return this.unbind;
    });
 </script>
```

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Check out this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=call+asp.net+server-side+function+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)...

Comment: Yeah could you??? I did google it and found nothing.

Comment: I found that already, I dont want to use web services for this.

Comment: Look at the "Related" questions in the bottom right of this page. They are filled with virtually identical questions.

Comment: @SamCromer It's literally impossible to invoke a server-side function from Javascript without using a web service of some sort. The question is whether it will be ad-hoc, using some standard technology, or proprietary but transparent. Ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to send a POST via ajax. If you're using [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax('/your/url/here.aspx?videoId=1');
```

Then in your ASP.NET code, add a page that checks the request parameter and saves the information to your database. If you're using MVC, it would just be a controller action.